# How Action helper communicate with view helper

Tags: php, zend-framework

I create a action helper file path is

C:\xampp\htdocs\ecom\application\controllers\helpers

file name :**Inputdata.php**

```
class Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Inputdata extends Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Abstract
{
    function Inputdata()
    {
        return $this;
    }


    function fetch_db_value($var)
        {
        if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()==0) {
            return is_array($var) ? array_map(array($this,'fetch_db_value'), $var) : nl2br(stripslashes(trim($var)));
            }else {
            return is_array($var) ? array_map(array($this,'fetch_db_value'), $var) : nl2br(trim($var));
            }
        }


    }
```

I am calling this function on controller giving output proper like :

```
$dbData=$this->_helper->Inputdata->fetch_db_value($dbData);
```

I have also a view helper, path is

C:\xampp\htdocs\ecom\application\views\helpers

file name : **Comman.php**

```
class Zend_View_Helper_Comman
{
    public function displayProducts($res){
                 # Res is a array           
                foreach($res as $val){
                  # $val also is sub array of array $res 
                  $val=$this->_helper->Inputdata->fetch_db_value($val); 
                  print_r($val)
                }
    }
}
```

this function

$this->_helper->Inputdata->fetch_db_value

is giving error

1. any idea about syntax how to user action helper custom function in view helper custom function
2. syntax how call function displayProducts() on controller

Comment: Just a heads up: Typically this would be split into two separate questions.

Answer (score 0):

Re: the action helper:

The namespace prefix on your action helper is `Zend_`. The autoloader will look for it in the location in which the Zend Framework library resides. In order for the autoloader - the resource loader, in this case - to look for the action helper in `application/controllers/helpers`, the namespace prefix has to be the `appnamespace`, typically `Application_`. So renaming the class to `Application_Controller_Helper_Inputdata` should do the trick.

Re: the view helper:

A similar thing applies. Typically, you would use the appnamespace prefix `Application_`. So renaming the class to `Application_View_Helper_Comman` should make the `displayProducts()` method accessible in a view-script as:

```
$this->comman()->displayProducts($res)
```

You mention referencing the view-helper method in a controller. This is typically not done; view-helpers are usually referenced only in view-scripts. However, if you really want to do it, you can access it via the View object. In a controller:

```
$this->_view->comman()->displayProducts($res)
```

If that view-helper is only going to contain that single `displayProducts()` method, then you can rename that class to be `Application_View_Helper_DisplayProducts` and reference the method in a view-script using:

```
$this->displayProducts($res)
```